# Android modify text on screen within a loop at runtime

Tags: android, c++, firemonkey

I am trying something as basic as pressing a button to execute a loop and display on the screen through the Text component, the value of the loop at each moment:

```
    void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
       for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
         Text1->Text = IntToStr(i);
         Sleep(100);
       }
    }
```

The text only changes when the loop ends and shows "9".. I have tried

```
Text1->Repaint()
```

and it still works the same.

Thank you.

Comment: You never return to the event loop during your loop. The OS doesn't preempt your program at arbitrary times to see what you've done (not even while the application sleeps), so your loop runs to the end and only at that time do you (eventually) return to the event loop and the final result is processed.

Comment: I understand that to create what I want (for this simple thing in Windows palatforma) a thread is necessary

Comment: No. A thread is not *necessary*. It's one approach, but certainly not the only one - nor may it be the best one.